# Back and forward buttons in Intelli-j 13?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have seen that the back/forward buttons in IntelliJ-IDEA 13 have disappeared. 
Any way to bring them back?

Comment: Why is this OT? Help center states *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* - this question is valid and on topic, yes?

Comment: I agree. This seems on-topic to me. IDEA is a java IDE.. i'm pretty sure that qualifies as a "[tool] used primarily for programming"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to enable View->Toolbar to roll everything back! ;)

Comment: You don't have to have the whole toolbar, you can add it next to the existing buttons on top. For this, you need to open Settings->Appearance&Behavior->Menus and Toolbars and there you can add the back and forward buttons to the Navigation Bar Toolbar.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer not to add the whole toolbar, but add the back and forward buttons on the Navigation Bar Toolbar, which is probably already visible: 
[image]

You can do this by going to Settings->Appearance&Behavior->Menus and Toolbars and there you can add the back and forward buttons to the Navigation Bar Toolbar. They are under Main Menu->Navigate menu.

I think this is much better than losing a row for the toolbar. To contrast this with the above image: 
[image]